# Load a component on passing id through link

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I have this link where I access multiple URLs by passing id.

Whenever I click on alert I want `query.js` to load and the id I passed through link must be available as props.

How can I achieve that in Next.js?

```
{Items.map((itm) => (
        <Link
          href={{
            pathname: "query/[itm._id]",
          }}
          as={`/query/${encodeURIComponent(itm._id)}`}
        >
            <Alert className="question13">{itm.Name}</Alert>
        </Link>
      ))}
```

```
import React from 'react'

export default function [itm._id]() {
    return (
        <div>
            
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: @juliomalves i have updated the question based on the answer u showed but it full of errors can u point out what i am doing wrong

Comment: `function [itm._id]()` is not valid JavaScript syntax.

Comment: @juliomalves ok now can u tell me how to read itm._id in that componenet

Comment: I'd recommend a read through https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/router.

Comment: Also note that the `query` page has to be a dynamic route, see https://nextjs.org/docs/routing/dynamic-routes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code it's work's

Your need to pass id like this !

in my app.js

```
{
  Items.map((itm) => (
    <Link to={`your api url/+${itm._id}`} />
      <Alert className="question13">{itm.Name}</Alert>
    </Link>
  ))
}
```

You need to import `useRouter` for access the query parameter

in my `[_id].js` file

```
import { useRouter } from 'next/router'

    const Post = () => {
      const router = useRouter()
      const { _id } = router.query // here `_id` replace with [filename].js
    
      return <p>Post: {_id}</p>
    }
    
    export default Post
```

Comment: i am getting _id as undefined

Comment: i tryed like this `const id = router.query; `     and when i console.log id i got like this    `{itm._id: '616bf26acb0ac0002363e4e5'}`  but i want only the value

Comment: You need to `const id = router.query.id;`

Comment: if you create `[id].js` this file then you will  get  `router.query.id`  value

Comment: now i am getiing undefined

Comment: can you tell me what the value pass in `[filename].js` this

Comment: like if you create [_id].js or [id].js file

Comment: its [itm._id].js

Comment: oky, i update my answer !

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240707/discussion-between-mayur-vaghasiya-and-jisa-ks).

Answer (score 0):

You need to write the `Link` Tag like this :

```
<Link to={`jquery/+${itm._id}`} />
```

Comment: OP is using Next.js which provides a built-in router and `Link` component, see https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/link.

Comment: This similar as react-router... :)

Comment: How do I load  the query.js component when clicked on link???

Comment: When clicked on link  a new page should load and there query.js  component should be shown

Comment: just add a route in your App like : <Route path="jquery/:id" />